# shell's && and || in python

Tags: python, shell, command

In shell if I want to execute a second command only if the first command was successful I would do this

```
cmd1 && cmd2
```

And if I need to execute the second command if the first fails I would do this

```
cmd1 || cmd2
```

I'm calling a list of commands via subprocess.call in a python script. How can I do the above?

Answer (score 7):

Pass `shell=True` to `subprocess.call` and you can execute arbitrary shell commands. Just make sure you [escape/quote everything correctly](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

```
subprocess.call("true && echo yes!", shell=True)
```

prints `yes!`, while

```
subprocess.call("false && echo yes!", shell=True)
```

prints nothing.

(You don't need to escape or quote `&&` or `||`, but filenames with spaces in them can be a pain.)

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @larsmans answer - If you're using `subprocess.call` and don't want to set `shell=True` for whatever reason, you can check for the `returncode` attributes.
If the return code is 0 the command was successful. You could also implement a `subprocess.check_call` to raise a `CalledProcessError`. Here's some helpful [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call)

Answer (score 1):

something of this sort will work

```
In [227]: subprocess.Popen(['dir', '||', 'ls'], shell=True)
Out[227]: <subprocess.Popen at 0x1e4dfb0>

 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4D5A-03B6

 Directory of D:\Dummy

09/14/2012  03:54 PM    <DIR>          .
09/14/2012  03:54 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  141,482,524,672 bytes free

In [228]: subprocess.Popen(['dir', '&&', 'ls'], shell=True)
Out[228]: <subprocess.Popen at 0x1e4df10>
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4D5A-03B6

 Directory of D:\Dummy

09/14/2012  03:54 PM    <DIR>          .
09/14/2012  03:54 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  141,482,524,672 bytes free
'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```